# How to access a <summary> tag with selenium

Tags: python, selenium

On this webpage, there is a button which I need to press. This is the HTML source:

```
<summary aria-controls="dc_2" tabindex="0" role="button" aria-expanded="false"><span>The company I am travelling with is not listed</span>
```

I tried to access it with the XPATH of the span tag, however it does not work. Any suggestions?

This is my code:

```
span = '/html/body/main/section[2]/section/div[2]/form/details/summary/span'
driver.find_element_by_xpath(span).click()
```

Comment: can you share a link to the web page and your code, what you tried?

Comment: The URL is private, however i can show you a picture. I will edit my question and upload the pics

Comment: Can you share HTML code, not a picture?

Comment: Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, have to see the page with dev tools, but possibly this may work:

```
"/html/body/main/section[2]/section/div[2]/form/*[name()='details']/*[name()='summary']/span"
```

Also, it's highly NOT recommended to use absolute XPaths as well as absolute CSS selectors. They are highly unreliable.

Comment: What shoud I use instead, I am pretty much a beginner

Comment: I hope you see I used `"` at the start and the end of the expression and `'` inside it?

Comment: BTW, what error do you see for your original command `driver.find_element_by_xpath(span).click()` ?

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/main/section[2]/section/div[2]/form/details/summary/span"}

Comment: This is what I get after using your line of code: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/main/section[2]/section/div[2]/form/*[name()='details']/*[name()='summary']/span"}

Comment: Try adding a delay before it. Just a sleep of several seconds.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235704/discussion-between-ianis-grigore-and-prophet).